# Cognito/Pinpoint integration - Lack of user-specific data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-pinpoint

I'm in the process of configuring AWS Pinpoint with AWS Cognito with the hope of tracking user activity within the app - Daily Active Users, Monthly Active Users, etc. However, after reading through the documentation, associating the Pinpoint project with an App client in the user pool, creating an IAM role for Cognito - Pinpoint communication, and electing to "Share user profile data with Amazon Pinpoint," the Pinpoint console only appears to be tracking endpoint-specific data (Daily Active Endpoints, Monthly Active Endpoints, etc) and Authentication metrics (Sign-ins, Sign-ups, etc). My question, then, is as follows: How do I configure Cognito to associate a user ID with endpoints so that user activity like Daily Active Users, Monthly Active Users, and New Users, can be tracked.

According to documentation on this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/integrate-endpoints.html

"When the AWS Mobile SDKs for iOS and Android register an endpoint with Amazon Pinpoint, Amazon Cognito automatically assigns a user ID from the user pool."

Below is a screenshot of the current state of the Pinpoint console.

[Pinpoint console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4YXW.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

JB